# How to restore panel's left side in Linux Debian 11 Cinnamon

Tags: debian

Now, when I tried to add the Thunderbird to panel, it added to the right with Files and Terminal as well.  I tried to right click in one of them, a small window popped up, then I select Preference > configuration, a big widow appeared with the line "allow dragging of launchers."  I clicked the top button on the right, and selected reset to default option.  It appeared in red both Files and Terminal, and no Thunderbird there.  Also, I could not dragged to the left since it doesn't work.
[image: Add Thunderbird to Panel]
[image: Hit Reset_To_Default]